# printf defined as void

Tags: c, printf, void

I figured out a way to silence all `printf`s at once, while reading [C-FAQs](http://c-faq.com/cpp/varargs.html).

Could you tell me how this is working. Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

//How to silence all printfs at once!!!

#define printf (void) 

#define ab a b c d e f
#define xstr(a) str(a)
#define str(a) #a

#define string "The politicians do not even know the" xstr(ab) "of politics"

main(){

char *all=str(a b c d e f);

printf("%s\n",all);
printf(string);

}
```

Output of the program is blank. I mean it does not print anything at all. If i `#define printf` as:

```
/ #define printf
```

This too behaves the same way. I am not understanding how GCC is compiling the calls in the two cases. No errors and no warnings absolutely.

- 1st case `printf` becomes: `(void)("%s\n",all);`
- 2nd case `printf` becomes: `("%s\n",all);`

Comment: The 2nd `printf` becomes `(void)("The politicians do not even know the" "a b c d e f" "of politics");`

Comment: Yeah, missed that somehow. Sorry. Just compiled with -E option and saw that :)

Answer (score 3):

C has a [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), which means that both expressions are valid.

Comment: Thanks, I had never stressed upon the comma operator. This serves as a very good example. Thanks again.

Comment: Note that code that actually *checks* the return value of `printf()` will start acting strange in either case.

Comment: Actually, there's a good chance the first won't compile at all -- the compiler won't be able to convert the `void` expression to anything testable.

Comment: It compiles fine. Both cases.

Comment: Only because the return value isn't used.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor is replacing the function as whitespace or void and that's why it is not called at runtime.

Comment: He knows it. He wrote as the last sentence of the question "first case it becomes XYZ" ezc.

Answer (score 0):

When it happens, both time it compiles to a bracket expression, which simply does nothing and returns the value of its last element (separated by commas - this is C's Comma Operator which you can see sometimes in loop conditions). Even if you don't cast it to void, the default setting in most compilers is not to warn about ignored non-void return values, so it compiles fine.

Comment: I always thought casting operator is not a lvalue. It cannot be placed on the left hand side of an expression basically. How would you explain this?

Comment: What? I don't even understand your problem... What about *(int *)ptr = 3; And amyway, the values you're casting are not being assigned to, they're just there.

Comment: Oh sorry, was thinking in the lines of (int *)ptr=3, Now i get it.

Comment: Can you tell me if my understanding is correct, *(int *)prt=3 works and (int *)ptr=3 does not, because in the first case, the value returned by (int *)ptr is fed to the deference operator which makes it into a lvalue.